# How to pass SIGALRM to a program which finishes execution in milliseconds?

Tags: command-line, scripts, signal

I have a C program which computes the first n prime numbers if n is passed as an argument.

```
$ ./prime 5
2
3
5
7
11
```

The logic of the program allows me to enter into a desired function if I can give `SIGALRM` to the process of the program.

So basically I have to enter

```
kill -14 <PID of prime>
```

in another terminal when 'prime' just starts executing, before entering the loop to find prime numbers. It is also to be noted that the PID changes every time the program is executed.

How can I concatenate all these actions and perform this in a single line command?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why one would write a program that requires receipt of  SIGALRM to enter a desired function.  Do you have the source code?

Comment: It is a challenge @Elder Geek.

Comment: @ElderGeek I have edited and added the source code.

Comment: Thank you for helping us help you. It's a bit beyond me as well ATM.  http://stackoverflow.com/ might get you quicker results. I'll flag it for possible migration.

Answer (score 2):

Create a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
./prime 5 &
sleep 0.001
kill -14 $!
```

You may experiment in adjusting the value to the right of the sleep command or get rid of it altogether.

Also note that especially on a busy multi-user system you have no way of guaranteeing that the process will actually get the signal.

**Edit**: borrowed the `$!` idea from murus answer

Answer (score 1):

The PID of the last background process can be obtained using the special variable `$!`. So:

```
./prime 5 & kill -ALARM $!
```